# Unable to initialize c array

Tags: c, gdb

I was writing some low level c code on fedora 14, but going nuts over this piece of code. The first array is not initialized to '0', the second is.
Gone through gdb several times, but it's like magic. What is happening?

```
const int maxsize=100000;
char num[7];
char tnum[6];
int pos=0;
while(pos<(maxsize+1)) {
  int c=0;
  int j=0;

  int myindex;
  int tindex;
  for(myindex=0;myindex<7;myindex++) num[myindex]='0';
  for(tindex=0;tindex<6;tindex++) tnum[tindex]='0';
//....
}
```

I printed the array values inside `gdb`, both as `p num` , `p tnum` and as `p num[0]` and `p tnum[0]`.
I also tried to initialize as plain 0, same thing also happens.

Here is the debugger output

```
Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at inversionscount.c:3
3   int main() {
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.13-1.i686
(gdb) s
5   const int maxsize=100000;
(gdb) s
6   int startarray[maxsize];
(gdb) s
14  int pos=0;
(gdb) s
15  while(pos<(maxsize+1)) {
(gdb) s
19      int c=0;
(gdb) s
20      int j=0;
(gdb) s
24      for(myindex=0;myindex<7;myindex++) num[myindex]='0';
(gdb) s
25      for(tindex=0;tindex<6;tindex++) tnum[tindex]='0';
(gdb) s
27      while( c=getchar()!="\n") {
(gdb) p num
$1 = "\370\377\277\270\367\377"
(gdb) p tnum
$2 = "000000"
(gdb)
```

Comment: What is the value of `maxsize`?

Comment: why is there an un-closed `while` loop here?

Comment: What makes you think they aren't initialized correctly?  It looks correct to me.

Comment: @skjaidev `bzero` is not a Standard C function and is deprecated in POSIX

Comment: OOOoh POSIX police! My comment stands. Use memset then!

Answer (score 1):

What is `maxsize`? Make sure the code follows the execution path you think it does, by single-stepping through with a debugger.

Also, you shouldn't repeat magical constants, the for loops are better written as:

```
size_t i;

for(i = 0; i < sizeof num; ++i)
  num[i] = '0';
for(i = 0; i < sizeof tnum; ++i)
  tnum[i] = '0';
```

or, since these are `char` arrays, just use `memset()`:

```
#include <string.h>

memset(num, '0', sizeof num);
memset(tnum, '0', sizeof tnum);
```

Comment: using `sizeof` as the exit condition of the for loop will cause the computation of the size each time. Guess it doesn't matter too much for so small arrays...

Comment: maxsize is const int with value 100000

Comment: @Saphrosit: No. In all but the most convoluted cases, `sizeof` is evaluated at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

How do you check you array are initialized with the `'0'` character literal? If you print them as strings, remember string are null terminated and your arrays are not.

Add this:

```
 num[sizeof num - 1] = '\0';
 tnum[sizeof tnum - 1] = '\0';
```

before printing them:

```
printf("%s\n", num);
printf("%s\n", tnum);
```

Also notice `'\0'` is the `int` value `0` while `'0'` is the printable character `0`.

Comment: Yes your solution works. Print f prints both as                 (gdb) s
29   printf("%s\n", num);
(gdb) s
000000
30   printf("%s\n", tnum);
(gdb) s
00000
 Was that a string terminating issue?Thank you.

Comment: @user1464460 By definition a string in C is a null terminated array of characters. The null character `'\0'` marks the end of the string.

Comment: Initally the problem happened when i gave input 0, mistakenly taking it for int, while was char. C needs much attention at these things :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use memset for both of your arrays:

```
#include <string.h>
char num[7];
memset(num, '\0', sizeof(num));
```

Comment: This probably isn't the solution he is looking for.

Comment: Why?  This is the standard idiom to initialize arrays in c.